# How to distribute div boxes vertically in bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Given some DIV boxes as follows:

#### [bootply here](https://www.bootply.com/voApyZtA0c)

```
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div style="border: 1px solid darkorange; margin: 1em;">BOX1</div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid darkorange; margin: 1em;">BOX2</div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid darkorange; margin: 1em;">BOX3</div>
    </div>
```

within a `body` that is set to 100vh height,

How do I use flexbox to make the green bordered DIV take up all the **remaining vertical space in the container**, and space out BOX1, BOX2, and BOX3 so that they all share an **equal height** within the container taking up as much vertical space as possible.

I have tried this:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
ng-component { width: 100%; }
div.app {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;      
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 1px;
}

div.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;

    border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

[image]

Comment: A visual representation of your desired output will make more sense. Please post a picture of what you are looking for.

Comment: I have posted a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly. I just added an extra class (you can rename it). Also, a container with `animated fadeIn`I gave new CSS. I made it flex but with column direction.

Then for the inner items, these bootstrap 4 attributes:

```
    <div class="col-4 border-1-2 d-flex flex-column align-content-stretch">
        <div class="d-flex col mt-0" style="border: 1px solid darkorange; margin: 1em;"></div>
        <div class="d-flex col" style="border: 1px solid darkorange; margin: 1em;"></div>
        <div class="d-flex col mb-0" style="border: 1px solid darkorange; margin: 1em;"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class='col-4 d-table'>
            <div class='d-table-row'><span>box 1</span></div>
            <div class='d-table-row'><span>box 2</span></div>
            <div class='d-table-row'><span>box 3</span></div>
        </div>
```